# How dynamically create a Character in Swift 2.1

Tags: swift, character-encoding

I have a file with this string:

```
N\u00e3o informado
```

Than I read it and put in a variable

```
let myString =  NSString(contentsOfFile: filename, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
print(mystring) // get "N\u00e3o informado"
```

Then I want to convert the `\u00e3` to your unicode value = `ã`. I read in Swift Book this line:

```
let text = "Voulez-vous un caf\u{65}\u{301}?"
```

And I tried create the same thing dynamicaly, but it didn't worked:

```
let substring = "00e3"
dinamic = "N\u{\(substring)}o informado"   //This produce the equivalent
print(dinamic)  // get "N\u{00e3}o informado" but I want "Não informado"
```

In the same way, this not work

```
let code = "00e3"
let caracter = Character("\u{\(code)}")   //compile error
let caracter = Character("\\u{\(code)}")  //runtime error
let number = 00e3
let caracter = Character(number)    //compile error
let caracter = Character("\u{00e3}") //This work, but isn't dinamic
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I read the string from a file. This is just to ask how can I convert the `\u00e3` (and ANY other code) to their character equivalent.

Comment: I can easy replace the string `"\u00e3"` to `ã`. But I will need to do for EVERY code. This will not be easy

Comment: A file with string. I get this from JSON. The text is exact the `"N\u00e3o informado"`, the `\u` code is in this way in a text format.

Comment: Lol, the JSON is not important. I can't change how it will output the string. But I need to read the file and convert it. I rewrite the question anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert your `String` to an `Int` telling `Int` that it is in base 16, then create a `UnicodeScalar` from the `Int`, and finally create the `Character` from the `UnicodeScalar`:

```
let code = "00e3"
let character = Character(UnicodeScalar(Int(code, radix: 16)!))
```

If you'd prefer to have a `String` instead of a `Character`, then:

```
let string = String(UnicodeScalar(Int(code, radix: 16)!))
```